# .NET Standard 2.0/2.1 EOL

Tags: .net, standards, eol

While installing Visual Studio 2019 updates (16.11.3), a small pop-up was displaying stating something to do with .NET Standard out of support.

I tried to look for the information regarding net standard support or release cycles etc. However, unable to find such information.

So, my question is, is .NET Standard already out of support or soon to be out of support?

Thank You !

Comment: I found this, does it answer your question? https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1681

Comment: Perfect ! Yes it does. Thank You ! @JoeSewell